# Open an already opened Activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an application and its Home Screen Widget.

Now from my widget when i press on a button it would open up my application from where it was left.

Means if i press home button during my application running then my application will go in background mode.

Now i want that it should resume my opened application.

Whenever i press a button from my Widget. How Can i Do it??

Please help

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've never made a widget before, but this is how I've made a notification launch back into my original activity when you pull down the bar and click it.

```
Intent originalActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Widget.class);
originalActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Once again, not sure how you would do this with a widget, but to relaunch it for a notification you convert that Intent into a PendingIntent to be called later when you want to launch back into it. I would assume this is a similar fashion for how you would it on a widget.